# How to merge two arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, merge, zip

I have two arrays.

```
let A = ["91","91","49"]
let B = ["9989898909","9089890890","9098979896"]
```

I need to merge these arrays and show it in the dropdown as

`["91 9989898909","91 9089890890","49 9098979896"]`

How can I get this result using swift.Im newbie to swift,can anyone please help on this.

Comment: is it confirmed that both array(A and B) size is same.

Comment: yes,both size is same

Comment: Sure the 3rd element of c starts with "91"? If so, then that's not really merging...

Comment: Why doesn't the third string in the array start with 49?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zip the arrays and concatenate the results:

```
let A=["91","91","49"]
let B=["9989898909","9089890890","9098979896"]
let zipped = zip(A, B)
let result = zipped.map { $0.0 + " " + $0.1 }
```

Comment: Working with parallel arrays quickly gets messy, `zip` is the neatest way to deal with them. This is the best answer.

Comment: Can i do this with three arrays

Comment: Sure, simply nest the zip calls: `zip(A, zip(B,C))`

Answer (score 2):

here is a snippet in Swift:

```
let a = ["90", "91", "92"]
let b = ["80012", "82379", "123712"]

let result: [String] = a.enumerated().map { (index, element) in
    return index < b.count ? element + " " + b[index] : element
}
```

Comment: Note that if `a.count` is more than `b.count`, you'd get: "Fatal error: Index out of range" error.

Answer (score 1):

```
let A = ["91","91","49", "5"]
let B = ["9989898909","9089890890","9098979896"]
```

Use `zip()` to join values from both arrays `A` and `B`. If `A` and `B` have a different number of elements, the joining would still work. then `map` the tuples from the zipped result array to those elements with a space between them

```
let C : [String] = zip(A,B).map {$0 + " " + $1}
```