# Display two array data in label swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have two `String` `arrays`, each `array` will have same number of elements. Now i want to show arrays data in a label text.

For example, `arr1["A","B","C"] and arr2["D","E","F"]` we have these two arrays.

Now how we can show data in label like this? `label.text = A:D,B:E,C:F`. How i can show data in this format in my label?. Array1 element should be first and second should be Array2 element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716749/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-swift)

Comment: Your link was also good to get the main idea. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: sure brother. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use **`zip(_:_:)`**, **`map(_:)`** and **`joined(separator:)`** on the `arr1` and `arr2` to get the expected result, i.e.

```
let arr1 = ["A","B","C"]
let arr2 = ["D","E","F"]

let text = zip(arr1, arr2).map{ "\($0.0):\($0.1)" }.joined(separator: ",") //A:D,B:E,C:F
label.text = text
```

Comment: Yes this is the right one as i want, thanks alot. Can i know what this map do? . @PGDev

Comment: `map(_:)` transforms every element into the required result. Read more about it here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map

Comment: so can i remove any specific string from array using map? @PGDev

Comment: @Hamza For that you can use [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3392999-filter)

Comment: @Hamza [Here](https://medium.com/@vishwasng/swift-higher-order-function-and-its-uses-d363eb5cc635) you can read about all higher-order functions